# grep + add time out after some time if not find the relevant match

Tags: linux

I use the following command syntax to search params in my script

grep -qsRw -m1 "any_param" /dir/..../

Some times the search take avery long time
The question is how to add time out to grep command

For example after 20 seconds grep will break out

If it not illegal to add time out to grep , how it will possible on other way?

THX
Yael

Comment: any other solutions maybe to katch proccess ID and then to kill it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a Linux command `timeout` that can do this for you. Just run

```
timeout 20s grep -qsRw -m1 "any param" /dir/.../
```

*EDIT*: If you don't have access to `timeout`, you could try this:

```
grep -qsRw -m1 "any param" /dir/.../ & sleep 20; kill %1
```

Afterwards, the process ID of the `grep` command will be available as the Bash variable `$!`. (I assume you're running Bash... if not, it'd help to specify your shell in the question)

Comment: [root@ ~]# man timeout
No manual entry for timeout
No my linux not have this command

Comment: any way this command not good because I need the $? of the grep -:)
yael

Comment: I all
any other creativ solutions?
Yael

Comment: @yael: running `man` does not tell you whether you have the command or not. Use `which timeout` instead.

Comment: [root@ ~]# which timeout
/usr/bin/which: no timeout in

Comment: timeout not defined in our linux
yael

Comment: If you are on a debian, `sudo apt-get install timeout`

Comment: I cant to install
maybe other solution
for example to see which proccess is grep and then to kill it?

Comment: How is it that you have root access but aren't able to install a program?

Also my edit basically does what you're pushing for, i.e. finding the grep process and killing it. If that doesn't work for you, what's wrong with it?

Comment: The solution is great, but it seems that it cannot be piped correctly, eg `tail -f file | timeout 20s grep "a" | sort | uniq` gives an empty result.